Why IRP_MJ_WRITE not trigger when do the file compressing?
I am devleoping the file filter driver on windows.
I want to detect the compressing operation on windows , so i listen the IRP_MJ_WRITE in my minifilter dirver and calculate the entropy to determine the file is compressed or not.
I expect when doing the compression form the buit-in zip button the IRP_MJ_WRITE will pass to my minifilter , but it doesn't.

I also write the code to test the compression operaiton , the following code will trigger the IRP_MJ_WRITE :
ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open("C:\\Temp\\test.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Create);
zip.CreateEntryFromFile("C:\\Temp\\test.txt", Path.GetFileName("C:\\Temp\\test.txt"));
zip.Dispose();

Furthermore i use the buit-in command tar to do the compression , it also triggers the IRP_MJ_WRITE.

Update
I found the root cause ... Yes , IRP_MJ_WRITE will be triggered. The
reason why i didn't found the IRP_MJ_WRITE was i filter the paths.
Because i only foucas on the specific folder path , so i return the
FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK if the IRP_MJ_WRITE not happened on the
specific folder path.
The build-in compression button seems to write the compression data to
the temp file in the AppData\Local\Temp\xxxxx(the compression data )
first , and then create the lnk object to the actual specific folder.
Ex.  C:/MyFolder --> I test the built-in compression button in
this folder.  C:/MyFolder/test.txt --> The file i want to
compress.  OS will write the compressed data in
AppData\Local\Temp\xxxxx  and then remove it.


I suspect IRP_MJ_WRITE is being triggered, but your monitoring tool is not picking up the correct location of the operations. How do you watch for these operations? If you use WinDbg with your own logging, try printing out all file names for IRP_MJ_WRITE. If you use procmon try filtering out all current operations to the FileWrite. It may be a case that a file is being compressed but OS uses a temp name, and renaming a file when it's done. As a side note, calculating entropy at a mini-filter level could be overkill at this low level. What's the reason behind this approach?

I register the FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION for IRP_MJ_WRITE event on PreOperation callback. But PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA passed in preOperation doesn't contain any IRP_MJ_WRITE in  (Data->Iopb->MajorFunction) , if i use the built-in compression button. However , if i use win32 api or tar command to do the compression , the IRP_MJ_WRITE will trigged ....   The reason to calculating entropy is for ransomware behavior detection approach.

I don't have a Windows machine at hand to test this, could you try downloading a process monitor and capture all FileWrite when you trigger compression via Windows GUI. I wonder what files are being written. It may be a case that when you compress a file the logic goes like this: compress foo.txt, create tempfile123.tmp, open foo.txt for reading, write to tempfile123.tmp, close foo.txt, close tempfile123.tmp, rename tempfile123.tmp into foo.zip. Oh, I see, you want to detect encryption, but it is similar to compression.

How are you thinking of distinguishing between a real compression and malicious encryption? For example, when MS Word saves a document, it can compress it. The user may encrypt some documents, e.g., if a user sets a password on a document. How did you consider distinguishing between malware encryption and deliberate user-requested encryption or compression?

@oleksii Thanks!! I found the cause and update the reason in the section.  My strategy to distinguish the ransomware is tracking the prcoess id which do a lot of encryption and change the file extension in different folder during a certain period of time.
